# Laptop wont boot

Tags: boot, laptop

I've got a chill blast Apollo laptop I bought brand new recently a couple months ago and everything has been fine until recently I tried to open it up and just nothing, even the charging led doesn't flash up, fans not spinning no sign of life, I've tried removing the ram sticks swapping them around, using only one ram stick, took the SSD out and put it into a different slot, I've tried running the laptop on charge without battery, I've put the battery back in and still nothing, the charger adapter works fine since I used on my all in one desktop, but I'm in a dilemma, can anyone direct me to a solution of some kind.

Comment: long shot but have you tried plugging it into another socket somewhere else in the building? if it starts charging, let it sit for a while before trying it again. dirty power at the socket can do weird stuff to complex electronics.

Comment: Is it under warranty?

Comment: As @DavidPostill states, don't make changes that might violate warranty -- take it back for help, repair or replacement: "I bought brand new recently a couple months ago."